# Bamboo Group Deploy Projects

Tags: bamboo

I have a numerous deploy projects in Bamboo that are used for deploying DevOps/release tools. I would like have all of these projects grouped together for easy reference. Is there a way to group or organize related projects in Bamboo? Ideally, this would be similar to how the build plans are grouped.

Comment: What is your main purpose of having them grouped? Is it purely organisational, i.e. to find them easily, or do you wish to perform actions on them - like deploy all of them with one click?

Comment: Good question. The main intent is for operational/orgaizational groupings, but a group deploy may be beneficial depending on the circumstance.

Comment: I the case of multi-project deploy, you should be able to create one "dummy job", which in turn has all the real jobs as dependencies. That way you could trigger them all via the dummy job!

Comment: Funny you mention that. That's exactly what we did :) organizational grouping woul just be nice so that we don't have to filter through a hundred deploy jobs just to find the one we want to kick off.

Comment: Just mentioning: Favorites. But you obviously done enough Bamboo:ing to have noticed. =)

Comment: Oooor... the old friend Ctlr+F =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an improvement issue open for, I *think*, exactly what you're looking for: [Bamboo should be able to group projects](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-1150):

> Description
>
> I'm mulling over redoing our project heirarchy and grouping things a
>   little more logically, and realize that being able to group projects
>   in Bamboo would be brilliant. It's already stellar that each project
>   can contain multiple build plans. Having project groups (a la Jira)
>   would make my OCD squeal. Any chance of this?

Comment: Yep, not the answer I was hoping for, but this is definitely what I was trying to find out. Thanks Dan!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else finds this question, I thought I'd mention Favorites. You can mark certain jobs as favorites, and then have those jobs appear on your "My Bamboo"-page.
That's obviously just *one* group, but still it might help.